# How to install Nvidia 319.12 driver on an optimus system

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a Samsung NP550 system with Nvidia Geforce GT650M. I have installed bumblebee 3.2.1 and "nvidia-304, 304.88, 3.8.0-19-generic" drivers are loaded for me. However I would like to update to latest 319.12 driver. I heard that this supports optimus natively [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/nvidia-releases-linux-graphics-drivers.html).

How can I install this driver? Do I have to remove bumblebee and install it or install it along bumblebee?

Comment: The same article does go on to say that this is all far to bleeding edge to actually work yet. Other things need upgrades before this will work. I'd suggest you stick with `optirun` for another six months and see what 13.10 delivers.

Comment: Try this answer

http://askubuntu.com/questions/289659/using-nvidia-319-12-with-bumblebee

Answer (score 5):

Try installing the new beta version of Nvidia 319.12 with bumblebee.

> sudo apt-get remove bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-current nvidia-settings
>
> sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319

Link http://orkultus.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/how-to-nvidia-319-12-drivers-in-ubuntu-based-systems-with-bumblebee/

Answer (score 3):

Bumblebee is an unofficial tool that brings Nvidia Optimus GPU switching to Linux. It's useful to increase battery life by only switching the dedicated GPU (Nvidia) on when needed. **Nvidia** has added initial Optimus support in their latest 319.12 beta drivers, **but it doesn't have GPU switching yet.**

[Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/bumblebee-321-released-with-ubuntu-1304.html)

Comment: What does optimus support mean, if it doesn't switch? Does it still save power as much as switching?

Comment: @nbubis Well optimums means ( here ) switching from integrated graphic card to High end card ( nvidia / amd ), In windows its is done automatically, But here in Linux its is done manually by bumblebee utility, yes its does save power, bumblebee switches it off until you manually run program from it. In kernel 3.12 Nvidia added an module and it will be done automatically so you have to wait at least few more days.

Answer (score 1):

I have made guide on this topic. It's step by step. Please see it here:

http://tuxilero.blogspot.cz/2013/09/how-to-official-nvidia-drivers.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent post in [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/using-nvidia-graphics-drivers-with.html) with instructions on how to easly install the new drivers with optimus support in ubuntu 13.10 thanks to the `nvidia-prime` package.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI.

If you decided to use bumblebee, please note that you can get better performance with `primus`

To install primus you can use following:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install primus`

And run you application with this command:

`vblank_mode=0 primusrun $APP_NAME`

This parameter enforcing better performance to use primus instead optirun.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing the newest nvidia-325 from xorg-edgers ppa. To do this, add these two PPA's:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

remove old nvidia drivers

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-304 nvidia-settings-304
```

Then install bumblebee and nvidia-325

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus nvidia-325 nvidia-settings-325
```

If you are using 64bit OS, you have to install an additional package primus-libs-ia32:i386

Then install Bumblebee configurator, using steps on this site: 
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/set-up-bumblebee-with-bumblebee.html

In this configurator, set Driver to nVidia and than in nVidia tab change Library Path and Xorg Module Path. Just replace nvidia-xxx (I'm not sure what will appear there) to nvidia-325. Then restart bumblebeed (you can do it through this configurator)

And at last, remove xorg-edgers ppa, because this ppa could mess with your system:

```
sudo add-apt-reposotory --remove ppa:xorg-edgers:ppa
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed it "The hard way" two monts ago. The performance is far better than with bumblebee. No powersaving though. I have played hours and there's no significan overheating.

You can check the how-to I wrote: http://zeronteproject.tk/74/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While your blog gives a complete guide, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.