# The last two times I have updated from the Software Updater, I have had to reinstall my graphics drivers and restart Unity

Tags: unity, nvidia, updates, compiz, launcher

The last two times I have updated from the Software Updater, I have had to reinstall my graphics drivers and restart Unity.

The first time it happened it took quite a long time for me to find out how to get everything back.  I am unfamiliar with Ubuntu and unity and I'm wondering why I had to do this.  Should I turn off Updates all together?  Are there specific updates that I should avoid?

For complete reference.  I will put what I did below to get everything back up and running.  I don't know if all of it is necessary, but I know it gets me back to where I was if I do it this way:

1) The machine comes up with nothing but a bad resolution and a mouse pointer.  So I kill the xserver by "ctrl + alt + F1"

2) I do the following so I can install the nvidia drivers again

- sudo service lightdm stop
- sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.23.run

3) I go through nvidia's rigamarole and reinstall everything

4) I restart and the resolution is clearly where it should be but I'm still missing Unity so I followed some instructions I found on this site

- [menu bar and launcher missing in ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286088/menu-bar-and-launcher-missing-in-ubuntu-13-04)
- dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
- unity --reset-icons &disown

5) The terminal I used to do step 4 obviously disappears but the unity bar never comes back up

6) That step 4 must do something funky to the metacity stuff cause I lose control over my terminal boxes so I run metacity and get them back

7) I restart my machine and everything is "near" back to normal (I lose all of my icons that I previously had on the launcher and gain some that I long ago got rid of)

So my main concern here is I don't want to do this every time the Software Updater has an update.  Is this a common problem?

Comment: Can you add to your question why you're installing the nvidia drivers by hand? This is a result of installing the nvidia drivers by hand instead of what comes packaged in the distro.

Comment: Please don't use the Nvidia `.run` file for this. Everytime you install a new kernel you'll have to rebuild it for the new kernel. Use packages!

Comment: Well to be quite honest, I don't remember the "exact" reason but I can tell you what comes standard did not support anything other than a really low resolution.  Also, I have been messing around with Steam for linux and I need to have actual nvidia drivers rather than the standard on ubuntu.

Comment: If there is a better way to install nvidia drivers, could you please send me a link to where that is?  I'm open to suggestions here :D

Comment: Ah, well, so if you really need the 319.x drivers or up you don't have so much options. Only to install the xorg-edgers PPA with experimental quality packages... http://askubuntu.com/a/289680/88802 (without the bumblebee instructions if you don't have hybrid graphics)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tips.  I am, however, still curious if the unity issues are also related to the Nvidia .run file being used?  Why would Unity just be missing?

Comment: I think the driver and unity issues are probably two separate issues, I would fix the driver first to make sure it's not breaking on upgrades and then move on to the desktop

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can use the nVidia .run files, IF you have Dynamic Kernel Module Support, dkms, installed before you start. It will make the driver rebuildable for a kernel upgrade.