# How to use Bumblee with Nvidia GeForce GT 750M?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

For the life of me I cannot get Bumblee to work with my graphics card. I attempted to follow 
[this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348614/bumblebee-on-ubuntu-13-04-with-geforce-750m-and-driver-319) to no avail, along with every other thread you get when you google "bumblebee GT 750M". Has anyone found away to use it with the GT 750M?

I don't so much have a problem with my graphics performance but with the power suck. I have tried to *just* load bbswitch, but after I make the file, and attempt to use modprobe I get this back:

```
ERROR: could not insert 'bbswitch': No such device
```

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on an Asus nv550jv Does anyone have any solution? Or any way to toggle my graphics card's power state? Thanks.

Comment: May be you can elaborate on what did not work in the thread that you followed.

Comment: I followed it, and I continued to get the exact same error described initially.